# Make left side of a pipe terminate when the right side terminates

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

cmd1 | cmd2

How can i get the sending command of a pipe to terminate when the receiving command of the pipe terminates?

cmd1 processes data from a file and its output is piped to cmd2.

cmd2 recieves cmd1's output and does some processing of its own which is output to a file. It has an option to terminate after a specified number of bytes have been written.

The problem I am encountering is that cmd1 continues to execute until it has processed all the data in the file it is processing, even though cmd2 has terminated.

This can take a long time and slows down my shell script.

---

Specific explanation of what I'm doing :

A "Super Agent" network probe device is capturing traffic and storing it in files on a 6 hour ring buffer. These are raw capture files in some format or other. A proprietary command can be used to build pcap files based on a time range. This is cmd1 from above and is called "buildpcap"

6 hours of traffic can generate a very large (200GB+) file.

I want to limit the total pcap to 10GB and split it into 1GB file parts.

I cann't limit the output of the file size nor split into multiple part files using buildpcap, but I can output to stdout rather than file, and pipe it to a command that can; in this case wireshark's dumpcap, which is cmd2 from above.

I want dumpcap to generate 10 x 1G files and then terminate. It does this but buildpcap keeps running for a signficant amount of time

The actual commands i'm using are as follows :

buildpcap --feed 3 --start-datetimed $start --end-datetime $end --stdout  |  dumpcap -i - -w ./tmp.pcap -a files:10 -b filesize:10000000

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: can you shortly explain what do your cmd1 and 2 do? if you try `yes |awk 'NR==100{exit}'` when cmd2 (awk) ends, the `yes` command ends too.

Answer (score 2):

That will very much depend on who/what cmd1 is, and how cleanly it was implemented.  For example, if I do

```
find / -type f | less
```

and from a 2nd window "pkill less" my find terminates.

Edit:

Taking the comment to this answer and integrating it with the answer:

In that case I guess you'll need a "watchdog script" that monitors the process status of cmd2 and kills cmd1 when cmd2 terminates. Something like

```
watch -n 5 'pgrep cmd2 || pkill cmd1'
```

should do. It will check for cmd2 every seconds and kill cmd1 if 2 is gone.

Comment: buildpcap (proprietary command on a network probe is cmd1) and dumpcap (from wireshark is cmd2). I don't think buildcap is well written. Some of the options work badly, so my guess is its not cleanly implemented. What options are there when cmd1 is poorly implemented? -Thx

Comment: In that case I guess you'll need a "watchdog script" that monitors the process status of cmd2 and kills cmd1 when cmd2 terminates.  Something like  **watch -n 5 'pgrep cmd2 || pkill cmd1'** should do.  It will check for cmd2 every seconds and kill cmd1 if 2 is gone.

Comment: @tink Why not turn that into an answer?

Comment: Thx - I'll experiment and give this a go, although it does seem a little messy :-)

Answer (score 1):

If `cmd1` tries to write to the pipeline after `cmd2` exits, it will receive the `SIGPIPE` signal. The default response is to exit (although it is possible `cmd1` was written to handle the signal differently).

However, if `cmd1` is busy doing other things and doesn't try to write to the pipeline, it won't be notified that `cmd2` exited. Here's one workaround:

```
mkfifo cmd1-to-cmd2
cmd1 > cmd1-to-cmd2 & cmd1PID=$!
cmd2 < cmd1-to-cmd2; kill $cmd1PID
```

First, you create a fifo (first-in, first-out) file (also known as a named pipe). Next, run `cmd1` in the background, redirecting its output to the fifo. Remember its process ID. Run `cmd2`, redirecting its input from the fifo. Instead of piping `cmd1` directly to `cmd2`, you've done so indirectly via a named file (hence, the alternate name of the fifo). Once `cmd2` exits, the `kill` command will be executed to stop `cmd1` as well.

If you need to, you can run `cmd2` and the following `kill` in the background as well.

```
{ cmd2 < cmd1-to-cmd2; kill $cmd1PID; } &
```